# Lazy Loading of References

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a java class with a member:

```
@Entity
public class TypeA {
    ...
    @Reference(lazy = true) private TypeB anObj;
    ...
}
```

Now when I do a `datastore.find(TypeA.class).asList().get(0)`, the reference also gets loaded and I get the message "WARNING: Lazy loading impossible due to missing dependencies." logged to the console.

What are the dependencies I'm missing and how do I include them?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to add this to your pom.xml (if you're using maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>[2.1_3,3.0)</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.proxytoys</groupId>
    <artifactId>proxytoys</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hey, I'm actually pretty new to java and am not using Maven. Either ways, what does this code do?

Comment: OK.  If you were using maven, this would add those jars to your classpath and then java could find the classes it needs.  Since you're not using maven you'll have to download them and add them your classpath manually.  You find those jars here:
http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=cglib/cglib-nodep/3.0/cglib-nodep-3.0.jar
http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/thoughtworks/proxytoys/proxytoys/1.0/proxytoys-1.0.jar

Comment: could you please help how can I add these dependencies to a wildlfly server as a module? We are using morphia 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT but we have the same issue like Gautham.